# WPF MaskedTextBox value binding (binding without the mask)

Tags: wpf, binding, wpftoolkit, maskedtextbox

This is my masked textbox from the [WPF Extended Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Home)

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox Mask="(000) 000-0000" Value="{Binding Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The binding back to the property is including the mask. For example, when I enter 9991114444, the `Number` property is set to (999) 111-4444. What I need, however, is just the value without the mask (9991114444). Can I accomplish that with the MaskedTextBox?

The number property is basic string property:

```
public string Number { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can just add

```
IncludeLiterals="False"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I guess their documentation is incorrect. It states that by default that is set to false :/